# paste an image (ctrl+v) to ngx-dropzone

Tags: node.js, angular, image-upload

Is there an option to paste an image into the drop zone of  ngx-dropzone angular module ?

can I add `(paste)` event to it somehow?

ngx-dropzone

```
        <div class="custom-dropzone" ngx-dropzone [accept]="'image/*'" (change)="onSelect($event)">
            <ngx-dropzone-label>
                <div>
                    <h2>Drop image here</h2>
                </div>
            </ngx-dropzone-label>
            <ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
                <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
            </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

found a way with paste event :

```
  onPaste(event: any) {
    const items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob = null;

    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        blob = item.getAsFile();
      }
    }
    this.files.push(blob); // insert to ngx-drop files array
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works perfectly! 
Surprised that this feature is not documented in ngx-dropzone package.